# Show that a countable infimum of stopping times is a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times, filtrations

Let $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ denote some stopping times and $(\mathcal F_t)$ a filtration continuous on the right, i.e. $$\mathcal F_t=\bigcap_{s>t}\mathcal F_s.$$ I want to show that $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}T_n$ is a stopping time. I don't know what's wrong in my argument:

$$\{\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}T_n\leq t\}=\{\inf_{n\in \mathbb N}T_n> t\}^c=\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{T_n>t\}\right)^c=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\{T_n>t\}^c\in\mathcal F_t.$$
I don't use the fact that the filtration is continuous on the right, so I think it's wrong, but I don't understand why. Any idea ?

Comment: $$\left\{\inf_{n\in \mathbb N}T_n> t\right\}\ne\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{T_n>t\}$$ Consider for example $T_n=t+\frac1n$, then $T_n>t$ for every $n$ but $\inf T_n=t$, not $>t$.

Comment: @Did: Yes sorry, but we don't have that $\{\inf T_n\geq t\}=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{T_n\geq t\}$ ? For example, $\{\sup T_n\leq t\}=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{T_n\leq t\}$, so why don't it works with $\inf T_n$ ?

Comment: Yes we have that -- but I am afraid you will have to much more careful and specific if you want to understand the necessity of the filtration to be continuous on the right. So, when is $T$ a stopping time for $(\mathcal F_t)$, already?

Comment: @Did: $T$ is a stopping time if $\{T\leq t\}\in \mathcal F_t$ for all $t$. Since $T_n$ is a stopping time for all $n$, then $\{T_n\geq t\}\in\mathcal F_t$ for all $t$, and thus $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{T_n\geq t\}\in \mathcal F_t$, therefore $\{\inf_n T_n\geq t\}\in \mathcal F_t$ for all $t$ and thus $\inf_n T_n$ is a stopping time. So for you this is wrong ? If yes, why ? Thank you.

Comment: First mistake: you are given a property of $\{T\leqslant t\}$ and you ascribe it to $\{T\geqslant t\}$.

Comment: The identity $\{\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}T_n\leq t\} = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{T_n \le t\}$ is obvious.

Comment: @Did: But I also know that if $T$ is a stopping time, then $\{T\geq t\}\in \mathcal F_t$, that's why I conclude like this. Is it wrong ?

Comment: @Gordon "Obvious" and wrong.

Comment: @MSE Yes this is wrong, because you do not know that $\{T\geqslant t\}$ is in $\mathcal F_t$, a priori only $\{T>t\}=\{T\leqslant t\}^c$ is in $\mathcal F_t$.

Comment: @Did: I see ! Thank you very much, it's clear now :-) And to have $\{T\geq t\}\in \mathcal F_t$ we need the continuity of $\mathcal F_t$, right ?

Comment: Indeed, without continuity this can fail.

Comment: Thanks @Did. It should be $\{\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} T_n \le t\} = \cap_{k=1}^{\infty} \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\{T_n \le t +\frac{1}{k}\}$, and then, by the continuity, we deduce that $\{\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} T_n \le t\}  \in \mathscr{F}_t$.

Comment: @Gordon maybe post the answer since it's not obvious the question is resolved (or OP can do it?)